# If $\lvert g \rvert=m$ is finite then prove that $ng=0$ if and only if $m\mid n$.

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

Let $G$ be an abelian group and let $g \in G$. If $\lvert g \rvert=m$ is finite then prove that, for $n\in \mathbb Z$, $ng=0$ if and only if $m\mid n$.

I think this amounts to proving that: $$ng=0 \iff \lvert g \rvert \mid n$$

This is my work so far:

> Assume $n=0$: Then $ng=0$ and $m$ divides $n$ for all $m$ so the statement is always true.
>
> Assume $n\neq 0$: $\lvert g \rvert \mid n \implies p\lvert g \rvert=n$ for some $p \in \mathbb Z$. So $ng=p\lvert g \rvert g$.

I think I should now show that $p\lvert g \rvert g=0$ but I don't know how. Can anyone help?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$$m\mid n\implies n= km\implies ng=k(mg)=k\cdot0 =0$$

OTOH, if $\;ng=0\;$ , divide $\;n\;$ by $\;m\;$ with residue:

$$n=mk+r\,,\,\,0\le |r|<m\implies 0=ng=k(mg)+rg=0+rg=rg$$

and since $\;m\;$ is *the minimal* non zero integer s.t. $\;ng=0\;$, we get $\;r=0\implies m\mid n\;$.

Comment: How do we know that $mg=0$? Is this just a fact I haven't learnt?

Comment: @john.smith That's the meaning of $\;|g|=m\iff g\;$ has order $\;m\;$ !